# Searching in multi-level tree structure

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class structure like below

```
public class Level1
{
    public ICollection<Level2> Level2 { get; set; }
}
public class Level2
{
    public ICollection<Level3> Level3 { get; set; }
}
public class Level3
{
    public ICollection<Level4> Level4 { get; set; }
}
public class Level4
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
}
```

I have an `IEnumerable<Level1>` object and want to search for a particular id in Level 4. If id is present, then set the `isActive` flag.

Any idea how to do it.

Comment: Try it yourself first, then post the code you wrote.

Comment: I really hope this is a homework exercise otherwise this smells of very bad data design.

Comment: This isn't a "multi-level tree" - strictly speaking it's a four-level tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` for each level that you want to skip. You can "chain" calls to avoid multiple declarations:

```
IList<Level1> list1 = ... //
var level4 = list1
    .SelectMany(item1 => item1.Level2)
    .SelectMany(item2 => item2.Level3)
    .SelectMany(item3 => item3.Level4);
```

Now you can iterate them as needed:

```
var itemsWithId = level4
    .Where(item4 => item4.Id == myId);
```

If `Id` is unique at level 4, use `SingleOrDefault` instead of `Where`.

Comment: @user641426 Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<Level1> level1 = GetLevels();
var idLookFor = 4;
var l = level1.SelectMany(l1 => l1.Level2.SelectMany(l2 => l2.Level3.SelectMany(l3 => l3.Level4.Where(l4 => l4.Id == idLookFor)))).ToList();
//loop all items and set flag:
l.ForEach((x) => x.isActive = true);
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, for those of us (like me) who can never remember `SelectMany`'s syntax, you can also do exactly the same thing with multiple `from` clauses:

```
// assume level1s is an IEnumerable<Level1>
var level4sOfInterest = 
    from level1 in level1s
    from level2 in level1.Level2
    from level3 in level2.Level3
    from level4 in level3.Level4
    where level4.Id == 4
    select level4;
```

Now `level4sOfInterest` is an `IEnumerable<Level4>` that you can iterate over and update as required.